# Sqlite single column update query is not working

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

My `UpdateRow` function is not working. Can someone help?

```
public boolean UpdateRow(String date ,String timeOut) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL_3 + "=" + timeOut + "WHERE " + COL_1 + "=" + date);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? Space is the cause of these kind  of errors add some space like "WHERE" should be "  WHERE  " or may be "=" be like " = ". And it will solve.

Comment: *is not working* How do you expect us to guess what is not wrorking ? Please take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think the query that you have written is missing a space between `WHERE` clause and `COL_1`. The line should be written as follows.

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME 
    + " SET " + COL_3 + " = " + timeOut 
    + " WHERE " + COL_1 + " = " + date
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes around `date` and space between columns:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL_3 + "=" + timeOut + " WHERE " + COL_1 + "='" + date + "'");
```

If `timeOut` is `TEXT` then it needs apostrophes too:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL_3 + "='" + timeOut + "' WHERE " + COL_1 + "='" + date + "'");
```